# Update of the element in the DenseVector class, Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

how is it possible to update some element with the index `i` in the object of the class [DenseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseVector.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible? Well, it is:

```
scala> val vec = Vectors.dense(1, 2, 3)
vec: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

scala> vec.toArray(0) = 3.0

scala> vec
res28: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [3.0,2.0,3.0]
```

I doubt it is an intended behavior though. Since `Vectors` don't implement `update` method there are clearly designed as immutable data structures.

Comment: It seems not to work in Java.... Of course I can code the Dense Vector with the dimension n as DenseMatrix with the dimensions (n, 1), but currently it is aternative solution...